# Changeing Size and other attribute of Fullcalendar Header

Tags: fullcalendar

I have looked through all the different occurrences of this question over the years and nothing in them seems to work.  I can't seem to get any CSS entry to change the appearance of the header elements.  Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to change these elements appearance?

I have spent hours and can't figure it out.

Some sample CSS that changed the appearance in this demo would be most appreciated.  (Buttons, Month/Title) Or an explanation for why that won't work.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fullcalendar-demo?file=app%2Fapp.component.css

Thanks in advance...

Comment: precisely what do you want to change? If you right-click in your browser and inspect the elements, you'll see that all the header stuff is within a div with the class "fc-header-toolbar", then there are divs for the left, center and right parts of the toolbar with classes "fc-left" etc. Should be fairly easy to modify any of these by pointing at the classes. What's your difficulty exactly?

Comment: Yes that is what I would have thought too.  Must be doing something silly.  Goal is to make the header smaller.  Now I would be happy if I could get any change at all.  "January 2018" is in a h2 heading inside fc-center.   I tried font-size, color, etc and cannot get it to change in my app.  So I tried in the demo app linked above.  No change there either.  I am not a CSS expert but this doesn't seem like expert stuff.  Were you able to add any CSS to the styles in the demo app that changed the classes you mention above?  I just tried again on the classes you mention and get nothing.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show what you tried, please? But trivially, see http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/168/ for an example.

Comment: Or in your demo (forked): https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fullcalendar-demo-r5vamc?file=styles.css

Comment: Thanks so much for spending time looking at this.  It seems it is some kind of ordering/timing/layering problem.  I have been trying the same CSS but putting it at the app.component.css level since it is component specific and not application wide.  That has no effect for reasons I don't understand yet.  But now I at least have a path to pursue knowing for sure the CSS that I was trying should work.

Comment: No problem. I would guess the problem with the app.component.css not being used it something to do with how AngularJS works, it's certainly not a part of fullCalendar. That file just isn't being included in the final output. You'd have to study the Angular documentation to understand what's going on, I think.